# Integrate Google Analytics to a Windows App installer created via QtIFW

Tags: google-analytics, qt-installer

I want to integrate Google Analytics to my Windows app's installer, created using Qt Installer Framework (QtIFW).  My intent is to simply track the number of active installations based on the number installation/uninstallation.  I would also like to collect a little bit of information such as OS.

Is QtIFW powerful enough for me to do so?  From what I gather, I can customize the installer via controller scripting or component scripting, but those scripting appears pretty primitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en) By sending hits directly to google analytics.

## Sending Required Values

To send user interaction data, make an HTTP POST request to this endpoint.

```
POST /collect HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com

payload_data
```

The following parameters are required for each payload:

```
v=1              // Version.
&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y  // Tracking ID / Property ID.
&cid=555         // Anonymous Client ID.
&t=              // Hit Type.
```

Comment: @dalmTo Thanks for your suggestion to use the measurement protocol.  I have actually integrated the measurement protocol to my app itself.  But with the installer created using QtIFW, I am unsure where to implement.

To elaborate, I know I can expand on [controller scripting](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/noninteractive.html) or [component scripting](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting.html).  But how can I make a HTTP POST in the context of the scripting?